# how to assign a slice of signal to single std logic without looping?

Tags: syntax, vhdl, slice, assign

I have this code

```
for i in 63 downto 48 loop
     s1(i)<= b(31);
   end loop;
```

I want to get rid of the loop , using one assign statment

something like that

```
s1(63 downto 48)<= b(31)
```

but it doesnt work because i am assigning a std vector to a single std logic

I want to assign the std vector to another std vector with same value (here b(31) )

Is it possible in vhdl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff's answer should do the trick in this case because the required type (including index range) is known from the assignment target.

But there are cases where it isn't, in more complex expressions, because `(others => x)` doesn't specify the size of the object created.

So it's also worth knowing you can explicitly specify a range in an array aggregate, and say

```
s1(63 downto 48) <= (15 downto 0 => b(31));
s1(63 downto 48) <= (63 downto 48 => b(31)); -- a bit clearer
s1(63 downto 48) <= (63 => not b(31), 62 downto 48 => b(31));
```

etc.

Comment: Assignment involves subtype conversion. The range in the aggregate doesn't matter as long as there is a matching element for each element of the assignment target. For use of aggregates in expressions the rules for when `others` use is permitted can be found in the VHDL standard IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates paragraph 6. The subtype (index constraint) are imposed according to paragraphs 7 & 8.

Comment: @user1155120 re: aggregate ranges, yes, the purpose of matching the indexes in the second version is documentation, not functionality.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
s1(63 downto 48) <= (others => b(31));
```